# Testlink - Installation - 404 Not Found

Tags: apache

I'm trying to install Testlink on my Ubuntu. I Have XAMPP running, and the Testlink folder is on /opt/lampp/htdocs/testlink

When i try to install in using http://localhost/testlink/install/index.php it says:

Not Found

The requested URL /testlink/install/index.php was not found on this server.

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you put the testlink folder?
If it's not the default apache location (usually /var/www/, I think) you should configure it to find testlink.
More info here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Answer (score 0):

For XAMPP - you should use the **XAMPP Control Panel** to confirm Apache and MySQL are running:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Start/Stop XAMPP
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Exec=sudo /opt/lampp/share/xampp-control-panel/xampp-control-panel.py
Icon[en_CA]=/usr/share/icons/Tango/scalable/devices/network-wired.svg
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=true
Name[en_CA]=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment[en_CA]=Start/Stop XAMPP
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Tango/scalable/devices/network-wired.svg
```

More info: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=223410

Also confirm file permissions on the **Test Link** files:

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/testlink
chmod a+w "/opt/lampp/htdocs/testlink/gui/templates_c"
chmod a+w "/opt/lampp/htdocs/testlink/upload_area"
mkdir "/opt/lampp/htdocs/testlink/logs"
chmod a+w "/opt/lampp/htdocs/testlink/logs"
chmod a+w /opt/lampp/htdocs/testlink/config_db.inc.php
```

Edit PHP configuration file: /opt/lampp/etc/**php.ini**

```
gedit /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini

session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.gc_maxlifetime = 2880

upload_max_filesize = 2M
upload_max_filesize = 5M

default_socket_timeout = 60
default_socket_timeout = 120

max_execution_time = 30
max_execution_time = 120

Register_Globals = OFF

memory_limit = 32M
memory_limit = 64M
In XAMPP 1.7.7 > already set to (memory_limit = 128M)
```

EDIT: /opt/lampp/htdocs/testlink/lib/functions/**lang_api.php**

```
gedit /opt/lampp/htdocs/testlink/lib/functions/lang_api.php
```

Change this line:

```
$t_lang_var = ereg_replace( '^TLS_', '', $t_var );
```

to:

```
$t_lang_var = preg_replace( '/^TLS_/', '', $t_var );
```

This has been corrected in: Testlink > 1.9.3

More info: http://www.teamst.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=2471

That should be enough to get you started.